# How to get foursquare user_id from user_name(twitter handle)

Tags: foursquare

I am using foursquare api v2. i am able to get details for people with their user_id. But it does not seem to work for people with usernames.
How can get userid from username to find more details?

Answer (score 1):

try the following URL:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/search?name=Fredrickson&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)&v=20150909

You can find user_id from Twitter name.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/search?twitter=basstrekker87&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)&v=20150909